# RuntimeException while using new TextInputLayout from support design library

Tags: android, layout, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I have very simple layout where I use new `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` view from [Design Support Library](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/support-library/features.html#design)

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textDialog"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="First Name"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

On inflate I get exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 18
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:401)
            at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedTextAppearance(CollapsingTextHelper.java:166)
            at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:106)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:381)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
            at com.example.trybindinglib.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2407)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5321)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

Comment: Wasn't 'fill_parent' deprecated 5 years ago? That should generate one more warning

Comment: did you find a fix for this problem? Im getting the same error. if you have found a problem, can you please post it as an answer :)

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767158/android-edittext-with-textinputlayout-crashing-when-reaching-limit-of-countermax

Answer (score 15):

Have you added the Design Support Library?
Add the dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

to your build.gradle

Answer (score 9):

If you are using `Theme.AppCompat` as your Base application theme, define the `textColorError` in it.
TextInputLayout needs it to use in it's error states. Else will show the crash log just as mentioned above.

Example:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="textColorError"> @color/design_textinput_error_color_light </item>
</style>
```

It is `@color/design_textinput_error_color_light` for `AppCompat.Light` and `@color/design_textinput_error_color_dark` for `AppCompat.Dark`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. If you wish you can set any other color you like.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure app theme extends AppCompat theme.

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

Comment: Mine extends appCompat, but still the issue persist

Comment: Thanks. This answer helped me.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on a raw application generated with Android Studio.

I solved it by first adding the following dependency to my build.gradle 
compile **'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'**

Then I had to modify the theme base to **@style/Theme.AppCompat** as suggested by Aleksey. 
Notice here that you will probably have to rename your base theme as there is one with the same name (**AppTheme**) in appcompat library, and AS seems to get messed between the two...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

getColor crashes, you can try two things:

1.Instead of using EditText, use android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText. For example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:errorEnabled="true">
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="First Name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

2.If that doesn't help, this might, but it will remove the color of your hint when the input field is selected. Add:

```
            app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
```

to your TextInputLayout.

Comment: After trying everything else, switching the EditText to an AppCompatEditText fixed my issue. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your XML looks like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="search" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

full example:

http://hmkcode.com/android-textinputlayout/

No themeStyle change needed