# Android EditText with TextInputLayout crashing when reaching limit of counterMaxLength after update of Support Library 23.2.0

Tags: android, android-support-library

In our app we use `EditText` with `TextInputLayout` to show validation errors. Everything worked fine until we updated to latest support library `com.android.support:design:23.2.0`. 
After this update app started to crash when it tries to show error on .
 Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/name_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:counterEnabled="true"
app:counterMaxLength="100"
>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/name_edit_text"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/group_name"
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapWords"
android:textSize="16sp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Code:

```
    nameLayout.setError("Error);
    nameEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
 @Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      nameLayout.setError(null);
}
}
});
```

Error:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: im.grouvi.app.debug, PID: 10704
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 3: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01010b a=2}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:482)
    at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:2757)
    at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.updateCounter(TextInputLayout.java:681)
    at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.access$300(TextInputLayout.java:82)
    at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout$1.afterTextChanged(TextInputLayout.java:242)
    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:8004)
    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:10165)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1043)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:560)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:492)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:491)
    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:685)
    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:445)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:340)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

### EDIT

After more testing. It crashes only when it reaches input character maximum set in `counterMaxLength`

Comment: In Android Studio gradle shows latest libraries number hint. So its correct 23.2.0

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Version 23.2.0 of design library introduced `Theme.Design.*` family of themes which mirror a subset of AppCompat themes but define this attribute on top of it:

```
<item name="textColorError">@color/design_textinput_error_color_light</item>
```

Either have your theme extend `Theme.Design.*` or copy the above line to your theme.

The `textColorError` attribute has to be defined in your theme in order to use error states in `TextInputLayout`. Otherwise it will crash just as you mentioned.

You can use your own error color value of course.

The default values are `@color/design_textinput_error_color_light` for light themes and `@color/design_textinput_error_color_dark` for dark themes.

#### Support Library 26.x.x

If you're using support library version 26+ it looks like this

```
<item name="textColorError">?attr/colorError</item>
```

for both light and dark themes.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved it. I used the solution of implementing textColorError in my theme.

Answer (score 2):

Its a bug which has been already logged here. Its not solved till 23.2.1 design support library.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202051

Meanwhile you can use the solution mentioned by @Eugen.

Answer (score 1):

Just Remove the style what you applied to the TextInputLayout.
This is due to Light and Dark theme differences..It's Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

use the stable material library 
implementation **'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'**