# android.view.inflateexception binary xml file line #53 Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi i have some error when running my application. I have a java files that calls a xml file to inflate a fragment. However when i run it i have an inflationexception. I have looked around but non of the solution seems to work for me. The code is able to run smoothly on emulators and some real devices but when i try to run it on my S3 the error is shown. I my java and xml files are shown below

LoginFragment.java

```
package com.example.ray.cdmsv2.Fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.ray.cdmsv2.R;

public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login,container,false);

    }

}
```

fragment_login.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Fragments.LoginFragment"
android:background="@color/white">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


        <!-- Logo -->
        <TableRow
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <!-- Spacer -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="10"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewFrontLogo"

                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="235dp"

                android:src="@drawable/logo_simtech"
                android:layout_weight="80"/>

            <!-- Spacer -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="10"/>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_username"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
            android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_login"
            android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forgot_password_link"
        style="@style/Blue_Font"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/forgot_password"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="actionForgotPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        style="@style/Button_Background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/action_login_short"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="actionLogin"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My LoginFragment.java is the file that is trying to inflate the fragment_login however when i try to run the code i have the following error shown

```
03-05 16:14:26.752 21537-21537/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.ray.cdmsv2, PID: 21537
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ray.cdmsv2/com.example.ray.cdmsv2.Activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                       at com.example.ray.cdmsv2.Fragments.LoginFragment.onCreateView(LoginFragment.java:16)
                                                       at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:904)
                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
                                                       at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6328)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
```

Help will be much appreciated

Comment: add

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: Sorry for the lack of stack trace i have added the full stack trace. Thanks for pointing up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android EditText with TextInputLayout crashing when reaching limit of counterMaxLength after update of Support Library 23.2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767158/android-edittext-with-textinputlayout-crashing-when-reaching-limit-of-countermax)

Comment: what suppot library version you are using ?

Comment: Oh i managed to solve it. Apparently is some theme issue that i had. Thanks a lot for helping everyone