# Appcompact EditText give Error on click of Cursor

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am using AppcompactEditText Inside TextInput Layout like below.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/name_et"
                style="@style/edittext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter your name" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Now Which problem I am  facing is

when i write text inside edittext then double click on Edit text so it give cursor for move  when i click on it its give error.

My logcat is show error like below:

```
06-07 03:58:10.856 16475-16475/com.demo E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
06-07 03:58:10.856 16475-16475/com.demo E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
06-07 03:58:10.857 16475-16475/com.demo E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class TextView
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
```

My Edittext style:

```
 <style name="edittext">
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/margin_3dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: did you using `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578976/android-textinputfield-inflator-error

Comment: post your `edittext` style here.

Comment: where is `style="@style/edittext"` ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya  have posted my edittextstyle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887518/error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-widget-appcompatedittext

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i was tried that solution but not working

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya in that solution it get different error see that logcat

Comment: There is something wrong in your layout xml file in line number 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have solved this problem .
What i had make mistake.

**I just Remove Fontfamily and Typeface from Apptheme and its solved.**