# RuntimeException when input exceeds counterMaxLength of TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library, runtimeexception, android-textinputlayout

I have a form with a `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText`. This is the relevant `XML`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/signup_til_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:hint="Name"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="16"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/signup_etext_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

When I try to input the 17th character into this field my activity crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 3
at android.content.res.TypedArray.twGetColorStateList(TypedArray.java:438)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:420)
at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:3029)
at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.updateCounter(TextInputLayout.java:688)
at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.access$300(TextInputLayout.java:84)
at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout$1.afterTextChanged(TextInputLayout.java:248)
at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:8929)
```

Apparently it has to do with not using the AppCompat Theme, but I am using the AppCompat theme already:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

Not sure if this is relevant but I'm also observing this `TextInputEditText` using Jake Wharton's RxBinding library, `RxTextView.textChanges(nameEditText);`.

Comment: Try changing `android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"` to `style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"`.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna That didn't seem to do it. I also tried removing `style` and `android:textAppearance` all together but I get the same error.

Comment: have you tried removing each attributes prefixed with `app:` ? Clean and rebuild.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna yes. No dice =/

Comment: What about adding `app:counterTextAppearance` and `app:counterOverflowTextAppearance` as  [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-EditText) example, And try seeing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767158/android-edittext-with-textinputlayout-crashing-when-reaching-limit-of-countermax) question, maybe similar as your one.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Adding those two attributes did it, thanks! Extending from Theme.Design.* also worked. Please post this as a reply so I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks bro for saying such..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest adding additional two attributes and giving it a style. one is `app:counterTextAppearance` and another is `app:counterOverflowTextAppearance` like here,

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  ....
  app:counterTextAppearance="@style/counterText"
  app:counterOverflowTextAppearance="@style/counterOverride">

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Those two styles are nothing but simply an item with `android:textColor` name like for example,

```
<style name="counterText">
  <item name="android:textColor">#aa5353cc</item>
</style>

<style name="counterOverride">
  <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

See the full explanation [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-EditText).

If that didn't work then I suggest extending the `Theme` from `Theme.Design.*` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35767811/5067493).