# UnsupportedOperationException on TextInputLayout when type count exceeded counterMaxLength

Tags: android

I have tried Shree Krishna's  answer provided in  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416530/runtimeexception-when-input-exceeds-countermaxlength-of-textinputlayout)

to prevent activity crash when input exceeds counterMaxLength in TextInputLayout. But what I want is to prevent further input not change in text appearance. How to achieve this in the code below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="15">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you EditText add this line, it will ignore input exceeding limit.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="17"
        android:hint="Name" />
```

Comment: yes u r absolutely ryt...   This attribute is applicable irrespective of  TextInputLayout