# App launch is crashing on app launch with Android 5.1.1 lollipop after xamarin update in visual studio

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-5.1.1-lollipop

We developed an app before for jellybean to nougat but now we're having a problem after updating our xamarin in visual studio.

Before, our apk is perfectly running in all Android version but now after update, it is now crashing... but only in 5.1.1. We already tested it with kitkat, lollipop 5.1, marshmallow and nougat, and it is really running.

We noticed that our app is crashing after the last curly bracket "}" in OnCreate method. It is launching an exception without prior detail.

What can be the reason for this exception? Or any solution if somebody already solved it.

I don't know if it's just a setting that has been changed due to xamarin update.

Exception only occur on OPPO phone as tested on other 5.1 and 5.1.1 version

Exception image is here and as I said, there is no single detail

[image]

**Here is the debugger output**

```
Android application is debugging.  
Mono Warning: option gen-compact-seq-points is deprecated.  
07-14 10:37:16.613 W/monodroid(18119): Trying to load sgen from: /data/app/RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1-1/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so
07-14 10:37:16.613 W/monodroid-debug(18119): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:29342,server=y,embedding=1  
07-14 10:37:16.953 W/monodroid-debug(18119): Accepted stdout connection: 29  
07-14 10:37:18.793 W/monodroid-gc(18119): GREF GC Threshold: 46080  
07-14 10:37:18.793 W/monodroid(18119): Calling into managed runtime init  
Loaded assembly: RBOS 2.0.1.dll  
Loaded assembly: BusinessLogic.dll  
Loaded assembly: BusinessObject.dll  
Loaded assembly: DotNetCross.Memory.Unsafe.dll [External]  
Loaded assembly: Newtonsoft.Json.dll [External]  
Loaded assembly: Realm.dll [External]  
Loaded assembly: Remotion.Linq.dll [External]  
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll [External]  
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.dll [External]  
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll [External]  
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll [External]  
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.dll [External]  
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll [External]  
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.dll [External]  
Loaded assembly: UTILITIES.dll  
Loaded assembly: Mono.Android.dll [External]  
Loaded assembly: Java.Interop.dll [External]  
Loaded assembly: System.Core.dll [External]  
Loaded assembly: MonoDroidConstructors [External]  
Loaded assembly: System.dll [External]  
Loaded assembly: System.Data.dll [External]  
Loaded assembly: System.Xml.dll [External]  
07-14 10:37:20.183 D/OpenGLRenderer(18119): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true  
07-14 10:37:20.193 D/Atlas   (18119): Validating map...  
07-14 10:37:20.303 W/ResourceType(18119): Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x01010099  
07-14 10:37:20.303 W/ResourceType(18119): Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x0101009b  
07-14 10:37:20.313 I/TextInputLayout(18119): EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.  
Loaded assembly: System.Web.Services.dll [External]  
Loaded assembly: Mono.Security.dll [External]  
07-14 10:37:20.903 I/Adreno-EGL(18119): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:   
AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C8.05.01.00.115.092_msm8916_64_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C8.05.01.00.115.092__release_AU (I6eddbfa548)  
07-14 10:37:20.903 I/Adreno-EGL(18119): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04  
07-14 10:37:20.903 I/Adreno-EGL(18119): Build Date: 09/16/15 Wed  
07-14 10:37:20.903 I/Adreno-EGL(18119): Local Branch:   
07-14 10:37:20.903 I/Adreno-EGL(18119): Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C8.05.01.00.115.092  
07-14 10:37:20.903 I/Adreno-EGL(18119): Local Patches: NONE    
07-14 10:37:20.903 I/Adreno-EGL(18119): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING  
07-14 10:37:20.903 I/OpenGLRenderer(18119): Initialized EGL, version 1.4  
07-14 10:37:20.923 D/OpenGLRenderer(18119): Enabling debug mode 0  
07-14 10:37:20.963 W/ResourceType(18119): Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x01010099  
07-14 10:37:20.963 W/ResourceType(18119): Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x0101009b  
07-14 10:37:20.963 D/AndroidRuntime(18119): Shutting down VM  
An unhandled exception occured.
```

**Example below**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.RequestAccess);

    #region Check if there is an active user - proceed to login, else proceed to request access
    UserAccountLogic.getAllUserAccountsFromDatabase(listUserObject);

    if (listUserObject.Count > 0 && listUserObject[0].isActive!=0)
    {
        //Call LoginActivity
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Login));
        StartActivity(intent);
        FinishAffinity();
    }
    else
    {
        txtAccessCode = FindViewById<TextInputLayout>(Resource.Id.layoutAccessCode);

        button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSend);

        button.Click += delegate { sendButtonClicked(); };
    }
    #endregion
    Android.Util.Log.Error("L", "Error Occured");
}//this is the place where exception occur in 5.1.1 . I don't know why.
```

If there is a user and is active. It will proceed to login. But same thing will happen. Will crash again on the last bracket of login.cs under OnCreate() method

Here is the LogCat output, it's hard to read for me since it's my first time to see it.

```
E/L       ( 6824): Error Occured // I added a log tag here before the bracket
V/WindowManager(  866): Adding window Window{386088e1 u0 RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1/md53392bfeb2a49aa0a04b6510289d0206f.RequestAccess} at 7 of 14 (before Window{3031e02c u0 Starting RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1})
V/WindowManager(  866): Changing focus from null to Window{386088e1 u0 RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1/md53392bfeb2a49aa0a04b6510289d0206f.RequestAccess} Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow:3410 com.android.server.wm.Session.relayout:202 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:273 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:130
I/Adreno-EGL( 6824): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C8.05.01.00.115.092_msm8916_64_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C8.05.01.00.115.092__release_AU (I6eddbfa548)
I/Adreno-EGL( 6824): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
I/Adreno-EGL( 6824): Build Date: 09/16/15 Wed
I/Adreno-EGL( 6824): Local Branch:
I/Adreno-EGL( 6824): Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C8.05.01.00.115.092
I/Adreno-EGL( 6824): Local Patches: NONE
I/Adreno-EGL( 6824): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
I/OpenGLRenderer( 6824): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer( 6824): Enabling debug mode 0
W/ResourceType( 6824): Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x01010099
W/ResourceType( 6824): Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x0101009b
D/AndroidRuntime( 6824): Shutting down VM
I/KSO_STAT( 1466): App is in background, stop update end time, ready to start a new session.
V/ExReceiver(32431): revceive action =android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
E/QCOMSysDaemon( 6861): Can't find/open bootselect node: (No such file or directory)
I/QCOMSysDaemon( 6861): Starting qcom system daemon
E/Diag_Lib( 6861):  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
E/QCOMSysDaemon( 6861):  Diag_LSM_Init failed : 0
I/Babel_ConcService( 5697): Acquired partial wake lock to keep ConcurrentService alive
I/Babel_ConcService( 5697): Released partial wake lock as ConcurrentService became idle
I/KSO_STAT( 1466): App is in background, stop update end time, ready to start a new session.
W/ActivityManager(  866): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
V/ExReceiver(32431): revceive action =android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
D/TelephonyProvider( 1787): simId = 0
D/TelephonyProvider( 1787): simId = 0
D/TelephonyProvider( 1787): query(): mccmnc = 51503 spn = SMART Prepaid simId = 0
D/PhoneInterfaceManager( 1787): [PhoneIntfMgr] getDataEnabled: subId=1 phoneId=0
D/PhoneInterfaceManager( 1787): [PhoneIntfMgr] getDataEnabled: subId=1 retVal=true
E/QCOMSysDaemon( 6864): Can't find/open bootselect node: (No such file or directory)
I/QCOMSysDaemon( 6864): Starting qcom system daemon
E/Diag_Lib( 6864):  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
E/QCOMSysDaemon( 6864):  Diag_LSM_Init failed : 0
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824): Process: RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1, PID: 6824
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class TextView
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.widget.OppoCursorController$FloatPanelViewController.<init>(OppoCursorController.java:1382)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.widget.OppoCursorController.createFloatPanelViewController(OppoCursorController.java:122)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.widget.OppoCursorController$InsertionPointCursorController.<init>(OppoCursorController.java:197)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.widget.OppoCursorController.create(OppoCursorController.java:75)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.widget.OppoEditor.getOppoInsertionController(OppoEditor.java:410)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.widget.OppoEditor.onFocusChanged(OppoEditor.java:298)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:8092)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:4963)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch(View.java:7679)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:7658)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2656)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2612)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2656)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2612)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2656)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2612)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2656)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2612)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2656)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2612)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2656)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2612)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2656)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2612)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2656)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2615)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:7625)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2019)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1116)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6084)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:773)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:586)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:556)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:759)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5408)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:401)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:709)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:645)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:60)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824):        at android.support.v7.app.AppC
D/ActivityManager(  866): addErrorToDropBox processName = RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1
W/ActivityManager(  866):   Force finishing activity 1 RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1/md53392bfeb2a49aa0a04b6510289d0206f.RequestAccess
W/ActivityManager(  866):   Force finishing activity 2 RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1/md53392bfeb2a49aa0a04b6510289d0206f.Launcher
W/DropBoxManagerService(  866): Dropping: data_app_crash (10 > 0 bytes)
V/WindowManager(  866): Changing focus from Window{386088e1 u0 RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1/md53392bfeb2a49aa0a04b6510289d0206f.RequestAccess} to null Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.setFocusedApp:4259 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.setFocusedActivityLocked:2553 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.adjustFocusedActivityLocked:2873 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked:3118
D/DropBoxManagerService(  866): file :: /data/system/dropbox/data_app_crash@1501223953398.lost
V/WindowManager(  866): Changing focus from null to Window{18da7c8d u0 Application Error: RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1} Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.addWindow:2660 com.android.server.wm.Session.addToDisplay:173 android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView:582 android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView:300
D/StatusBarManagerService(  866): manageDisableList userId=0 what=0x0 pkg=Window{18da7c8d u0 Application Error: RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1}
W/ActivityManager(  866):  Dismiss app error dialog : RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1
V/WindowManager(  866): Changing focus from Window{18da7c8d u0 Application Error: RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1} to null Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2830 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2739 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2729 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:192
I/Process ( 6824): Sending signal. PID: 6824 SIG: 9
V/Process ( 6824): killProcess [6824] Callers=com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:99 android.runtime.UncaughtExceptionHandler.n_uncaughtException:-2 android.runtime.UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException:37 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693
I/WindowState(  866): WIN DEATH: Window{2ec5203a u0 RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1/md53392bfeb2a49aa0a04b6510289d0206f.Launcher}
I/WindowState(  866): WIN DEATH: Window{386088e1 u0 RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1/md53392bfeb2a49aa0a04b6510289d0206f.RequestAccess}
D/WindowStateAnimator(  866): finishExit add win to mPendingRemove. win:Window{386088e1 u0 RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1/md53392bfeb2a49aa0a04b6510289d0206f.RequestAccess}
I/ActivityManager(  866): Process RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1 (pid 6824) has died
V/WindowManager(  866): Changing focus from null to Window{8939001 u0 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings} Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow:3410 com.android.server.wm.Session.relayout:202 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:273 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:130
D/StatusBarManagerService(  866): manageDisableList userId=0 what=0x0 pkg=Window{8939001 u0 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings}
W/InputMethodManagerService(  866): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@29eee4cb attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@129961e8
D/AndroidRuntime( 6867): >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 6867): CheckJNI is OFF
E/jniPro  ( 6867): protecteyesinit, try to dlopen arm32 so:/system/lib/libprotecteyes.so
E/jniPro  ( 6867): protecteyesinit, dlopen arm32 so:/system/lib/libprotecteyes.so, open ***success****, now dlerror info: (null)
D/AndroidRuntime( 6867): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
D/ActivityManager(  866): for debug: forceStopPackage[pkg:RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1,userId:-1], caller[pid:6867,uid:2000]
I/ActivityManager(  866): Force stopping RBOS_2.x_0.x_1.RBOS_2.x_0.x_1 appid=10189 user=0: from pid 6867
D/AndroidRuntime( 6867): Shutting down VM
I/KSO_STAT( 1466): App is in background, stop update end time, ready to start a new session.
E/QCOMSysDaemon( 6886): Can't find/open bootselect node: (No such file or directory)
I/QCOMSysDaemon( 6886): Starting qcom system daemon
E/Diag_Lib( 6886):  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
E/QCOMSysDaemon( 6886):  Diag_LSM_Init failed : 0
D/TaskPersister(  866): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=354_task.xml
```

** **UPDATE FOR XML and Style** **

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:alpha="0.9"
  android:background="@drawable/rbos_2"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:weightSum="100">
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="55"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
      android:src="@drawable/dtglogo3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:id="@+id/imgLogo" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="45"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:gravity="top"
      android:paddingLeft="25dp"
      android:paddingRight="25dp">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutAccessCode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
        <!--android:background="@drawable/layouttextbox"-->
      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/txtAccessCode"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
          android:maxLength="15"
          android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqr‌​stuvwxyz0123456789"
          android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
          android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"
          android:imeOptions="actionDone"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:hint="Access Code" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:theme="@style/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#e4ecd4"
        android:background="@drawable/layoutbutton"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <TextView
    android:text="@string/versionName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:textSize="6dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="#0d47a1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my previous style

```
<!-- Input Layout -->
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
  <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
  <item name="android:textColorHint">#000000</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
  <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
  <item name="colorAccent">#0d47a1</item>
  <item name="colorControlNormal">#000000</item>
  <item name="colorControlActivated">#0d47a1</item>
</style>
```

** **PROBLEM SOLVED** **

As suggested, I may need to change the parent of style from *TextAppearance.AppCompat* to *Widget.Design.TextInputLayout* . I tried and it works!
THANKS ALOT!

*Just for a note of testing for other coders
It's just that, i'm wondering why only in OPPO 5.1.1 . Other android versions I tried with and working are here
-Marshmallow and Nougat with Asus 6.0 & 7.0
-Kitkat and Marshmallow Starmobile 4.4 & 6.0
-JellyBean, Kitkat and Marshmallow with Samsung 4.2, 4.4 & 6.0
-Other brand with 5.1 and 5.1.1 (not the OPPO)

Comment: can you post your exception?

Comment: Please say the exception. but try a clean and rebuild before that

Comment: post updated sir

Comment: hard to say without being able to reproduce but if you have sample project where that happens it will be a good place to start

Comment: You need to update your API version to 7.0

Comment: why? and what do you mean the API version? the version of the android phone or my sdk version as I dev?

Comment: have you tried changing the starting view with another that is much more simpler (like a linearlayout with a textview)? Have you looked what the Device log says?

Comment: i already updated it with LogCat and will now test with new project. But also I tried commenting all codes inside oncreate() and still got an error

Comment: Please do not indicate that the question is solved in the question itself. Feel free to accept an answer, comment on relevant answers, or even answer your own question if the other answers don't provide a full picture.

Comment: Have you read the accepted answer and my comment on it? I already did that before your comment, then what's your problem? sorry i'm confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your styles colours.

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class TextView
```

.../...

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24
E/AndroidRuntime( 6824): at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:401)
```

Which I assume if coming from here:

```
txtAccessCode = FindViewById<TextInputLayout>(Resource.Id.layoutAccessCode);
```

Without seeing your styles, you can try something like this:

[For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36719457/3956566) ensure that the TextView is inheriting from the `Widget.Design.TextInputLayout`:

```
<style name="TextViewStyle" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
```

and that you've included the `Design Support Library` dependency.

If you want a more specific answer, please add your styles code, xml/layout, the `layoutAccessCode`  and build dependencies.

Look at the answers to these two questions:

[Android XML: RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595187/android-xml-runtimeexception-failed-to-resolve-attribute-at-index-6)

[TextInputLayout: RuntimeException - Failed to resolve attribute at index 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956609/textinputlayout-runtimeexception-failed-to-resolve-attribute-at-index-24)

[RuntimeException while using new TextInputLayout from support design library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551229/runtimeexception-while-using-new-textinputlayout-from-support-design-library)

Comment: You've made my day ! :) thank alot ! . I updated my posts, and I put there everything. The problem was solved by changing the parent of my style. I'm now testing it with 5.1.1 and the other. I'm just